# PostgreSQL Window Functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Consider the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_log
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  moment DATE,
  old INTEGER,
  actual INTEGER
);
```

Containing the data:

```
INSERT INTO
  tb_log ( id, moment, old, actual )
VALUES
  ( 1, '2018-06-19', 10, 20 ),
  ( 2, '2018-06-21', 20, 30 ),
  ( 3, '2018-06-25', 30, 40 );
```

I'm trying to get from `tb_log` the period (start date and end date) at which a value was in effect.

**Trial #1** - Using `lag()` function:

```
SELECT
  lag( moment ) OVER (ORDER BY moment) date_start,
  moment AS date_end,
  old AS period_value
FROM
   tb_log;
```

Which returns the following data:

```
| date_start |   date_end | period_value |
|------------|------------|--------------|
|     (null) | 2018-06-19 |           10 |
| 2018-06-19 | 2018-06-21 |           20 |
| 2018-06-21 | 2018-06-25 |           30 |
```

**Trial #2** - Using `lead()` function:

```
SELECT
  moment AS date_start,
  lead( moment ) OVER (ORDER BY moment) date_end,
  actual AS period_value
FROM
   tb_log;
```

Which returns the following data:

```
| date_start |   date_end | period_value |
|------------|------------|--------------|
| 2018-06-19 | 2018-06-21 |           20 |
| 2018-06-21 | 2018-06-25 |           30 |
| 2018-06-25 |     (null) |           40 |
```

[SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7a7ea/4)

Is there any trick using `Window Functions` to return something like this:

```
| date_start |   date_end | period_value |
|------------|------------|--------------|
|     (null) | 2018-06-19 |           10 |
| 2018-06-19 | 2018-06-21 |           20 |
| 2018-06-21 | 2018-06-25 |           30 |
| 2018-06-25 |     (null) |           40 |
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no trick using window functions, because window functions do not add a row to the data.  It is much more natural (in my opinion) to use `lead()`:

```
(SELECT moment, lead(moment) over (order by moment) as date_end,
       actual AS period_value
 FROM tb_log
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT null, moment, old
 FROM tb_log
 ORDER BY moment
 LIMIT 1
);
```

In general, using `union all` instead of `union` is a good idea.  `Union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

```
    SELECT
      lag( moment ) OVER (ORDER BY moment) date_start,
      moment AS date_end,
      old AS period_value
    FROM
       tb_log
    union
    SELECT
      moment AS date_start,
      lead( moment ) OVER (ORDER BY moment) date_end,
      actual AS period_value
    FROM
       tb_log
order by 3;
```